# value of f32::NAN rust closure for omitting 'NaN' values

Tags: rust

I have the following closure.

```
let ss = aa.iter().fold(0., |sum: f32,x| if *x != f32::NAN { sum + e } else { sum + 0. })
```

I am trying to sum all the values omitting `f32::NAN` if any in the vector(I have couple of `NaN` values in the vector).

But, My return gives me `NaN` value because my condition `if *x != f32::NAN` does not seem to be valid. Because, the following closure yields the original vector instead of omitting `NaN` value.

```
let bb = aa.iter().filter(|x| **x != f32::NAN).map(|x| x)
```

My question is, how do I match `f32::NAN` value in a `if` condition?
In a broader perspective, How do I omit `NaN` values in a vector?

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN

Comment: More FYI: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.is_nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right directional help of `Warren Weckesser` Managed to make the closure work.

Here is the solution for those who might need.

```
let ss = aa.iter().fold(0., |sum: f32, x| if x.is_nan() { sum + 0. } else { sum + x });
```

Alternatively,

```
let ss = aa.iter().fold(0., |sum: f32, x| if x.is_nan() { sum } else { sum + x });
```

if one cares about a unnecessary `+` operation.

**Performance Comparison**

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
fn main() {
    let mut a [f32; 1000] = [0.; 1000];
    for i in 0..1000 {
        a[i] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1,11);
    }
}
```

**Approach-I:**

```
let ss = a.iter()
        .filter(|n| !n.is_nan())
        .sum::<f32>();
```

***Callgrind***

```
>> cargo profiler callgrind -n 10

Compiling playground in debug mode...

Profiling playground with callgrind...

Total Instructions...3,959,454

177,532 (4.5%) isaac64.rs:rand::prng::isaac64::Isaac64Rng::isaac64
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
121,742 (3.1%) memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
104,224 (2.6%) dl-lookup.c:do_lookup_x
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
102,982 (2.6%) ptr.rs:core::ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
99,660 (2.5%) intrinsics.rs:core::intrinsics::copy_nonoverlapping
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
76,555 (1.9%) strcmp.S:strcmp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
72,997 (1.8%) local.rs:_..std..thread..local..LocalKey..T....::try_with
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
72,063 (1.8%) ptr.rs:_..core..ptr..NonNull..T....::as_ref
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
70,028 (1.8%) rc.rs:alloc::rc::RcBoxPtr::strong
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
62,000 (1.6%) ptr.rs:core::ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Approach-II:**

```
let ss = a.iter()
        .fold(0., |sum: f32, x| if x.is_nan() { sum } else { sum + x });
```

**Callgrind**

```
>> cargo profiler callgrind -n 10

Compiling playground in debug mode...

Profiling playground with callgrind...

Total Instructions...3,938,312

177,532 (4.5%) isaac64.rs:rand::prng::isaac64::Isaac64Rng::isaac64
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
121,766 (3.1%) memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
104,224 (2.6%) dl-lookup.c:do_lookup_x
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
102,982 (2.6%) ptr.rs:core::ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
99,660 (2.5%) intrinsics.rs:core::intrinsics::copy_nonoverlapping
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
76,555 (1.9%) strcmp.S:strcmp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
72,997 (1.9%) local.rs:_..std..thread..local..LocalKey..T....::try_with
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
72,063 (1.8%) ptr.rs:_..core..ptr..NonNull..T....::as_ref
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
70,028 (1.8%) rc.rs:alloc::rc::RcBoxPtr::strong
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
62,000 (1.6%) ptr.rs:core::ptr::swap_nonoverlapping_one
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looking at the *Total Instructions*, **Approach-II** fares well in terms of run-time performance with `~20,000` instructions less than **Approach-I** for `1000` element array. Anticipating this difference will positively translate in to enhanced run-time performance for **Approach-II**. Investigating, from where the difference stem from.

Comment: Yes @Stargateur. I use `let _mean = aa.iter().fold(0., |sum: f32, x| sum + *x)`. Initially I had `sum` a mutable variable as `mut sum` however compiler suggested me that doesn't need to be. I am trying to understand why though. Your insight is welcome here on this.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot check for NaN that way, since `NaN == NaN` evaluates to `false`. Use [`f32::is_nan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.is_nan) instead. Furthermore, you can use [`Iterator::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) to filter out elements of an iterator and [`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) to sum all values.

This results in this code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=526ae9e1b18e32fca5d9667a7671a9ed)):

```rust
let aa = [3.14f32, std::f32::NAN, 2.71, 27.99];
let ss = aa.iter()
    .filter(|n| !n.is_nan())
    .sum::<f32>();

println!("{}", ss);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Kalbertodt. I learnt `sum::<T>` method from your answer. Using `filter` chained with `sum::<T>` looks more idiomatic.